# How to update a dataframe cells based on matching condition from another data frame. There are multiple matching rows and data to be updated is list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This is the dataframe which needs to be updated.

```
   ID       Doctor_Name  ... Doctor_Office_Zipcode website
0   1       Wendy Mayer  ...                 10019      []
1   2  Michael S. Tseng  ...                 10017      []
```

This is the second dataframe from where we need to pick matching values

```
                         name                                      website
0         Dr. Wendy Mayer DDS                      ['mayerdentalcare.com']
1          Dr. Usha Gorti DDS                     ['westenddentalnyc.com']
2  Dr. Alexander J. Antonakos  ['newyorkcosmeticdental.com', 'zocdoc.com']
```

Problem : I need to update the website in the first dataframe where there is a match from the second dataframe. there may be multiple rows that matches in second data frame. I need to pick the first matching value and update in the original dataframe.

After using this code am getting Nan at all places.

I want something like this

```
   ID       Doctor_Name  ... Doctor_Office_Zipcode website
0   1       Wendy Mayer  ...                 10019      ['mayerdentalcare.com']
1   2  Michael S. Tseng  ...                 10017      ['newyorktseng.com', 'zocy.com']
```

Here is my code:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(orig)
web_data = pd.read_csv(website)
raw_data['website'] = np.empty((len(raw_data), 0)).tolist()
for x in raw_data['Doctor_Name']:
    print('now searching for {}', x)
    values = web_data[web_data['name'].str.contains(x, case=False, na=False, regex=False)]
    if values is not None and values.size > 0:
        y = values['website'].iloc[:1]
        raw_data.loc[raw_data['Doctor_Name'] == x, 'website'] = values.head(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` to extract the matched `Doctor_Name` from df2's `name` column

```py
df2['Doctor_Name'] = df2['name'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(df1['Doctor_Name'])+')')
```

```
print(df2)

                         name                                      website  Doctor_Name
0         Dr. Wendy Mayer DDS                      ['mayerdentalcare.com']  Wendy Mayer
1          Dr. Usha Gorti DDS                     ['westenddentalnyc.com']          NaN
2  Dr. Alexander J. Antonakos  ['newyorkcosmeticdental.com', 'zocdoc.com']          NaN
```

Then `merge` on the matched name and drop the possible multiple matches

```py
df1['website'] = df1.merge(df2, on='Doctor_Name', how='left').drop_duplicates('Doctor_Name')['website_y']
```

```
print(df1)

   ID       Doctor_Name  Doctor_Office_Zipcode                  website
0   1       Wendy Mayer                  10019  ['mayerdentalcare.com']
1   2  Michael S. Tseng                  10017                      NaN
```